# turning one column into multiple pro-rated column

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data regarding an insurance customer's premium during a certain year.

| User ID | Period From | Period to | Period from-period to | Total premium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A8856 | Jan 2022 | Apr 2022 | 4 | $600 |
| A8857 | Jan 2022 | Feb 2022 | 2 | $400 |

And I'm trying to turn it into a pro-rated one

Assuming that the input I'm expecting is like this:

| User ID | Period From | Total premium |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A8856 | Jan 2022 | $150 |
| A8856 | Feb 2022 | $150 |
| A8856 | Mar 2022 | $150 |
| A8856 | Apr 2022 | $150 |
| A8857 | Jan 2022 | $200 |
| A8857 | Feb 2022 | $200 |

What kind of code do you think I should use? I use python and help is really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code here and ask specifically about that code. Also, are you sure you are on Python 2? Do you need to be, because there's hardly any reason to be using it in 2023.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.